# how to get image Details form mobile folder location

Tags: image, file, cordova, phonegap-plugins, file-location

We have image path like

```
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/1395167011485.jpg.
```

OR

```
file://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/1395167011485.jpg.
```

We need get image details using this path.Image details like Image Name,height, width.We are developing `Cordova` mobile apps.Please guide to us .Which plugin we need use for Details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a specific plugin, though you could use [file transfer](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/) to help with it. Something like the following will work fine:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src = "img/My_Image.png";
console.log(image.height);
console.log(image.width);
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this javascript exif library](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) useful.

Comment: Thanks for reply I flowed this https://github.com/guilhermefarias/cordova-exif Yes we can get Image Details but problem is We are getting only JPG images only We need to get PNG image also

Comment: (Good to know about the plugin) Seems exif not applied to png. Don't have an answer for you. However, did just find a a node package jsgui-node-png-metadata which you might get something out of if the code is in js or even C++ if you used emscripten on it.